# how to set multiple options to one field with ; seperated with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm really new and would like to know how I can fill in selected options to one line like "test1;test2;test3" which will be saved in a hidden field.

This needs to be done by looping.

Hope you understand what I mean ^^ as my english is not sooo good.

here an example:

Till now I could loop it that it returns each time one value of the option and now I don't know how I can itegrate that each time if it catch one value from the option to store it in only one variable.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="from[]" class="js-multiselect form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="5">Item 5</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" id="js_right_All_1" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="js_right_Selected_1" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="js_left_Selected_1" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="js_left_All_1" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="to[]" onChange="updateSelectedValues()" id="js_multiselect_to_1" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input name="ValuesToSelected[]" maxlength="500" id="ValuesToSelected">


<script>
  function updateSelectedValues() {

    var toPopulationRoles = document.getElementById('js_multiselect_to_1'),
      selectedPopRole, i;


    for (i = 0; i < toPopulationRoles.length; i++) {
      selectedPopRole = toPopulationRoles[i];

      if (selectedPopRole.selected) {
        alert(selectedPopRole.value);


      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If multpile options are moved to the right box then the options should be stored in the hidden field like: Item1;Item2;Item3;

Comment: getElementById returns null or a single DOM object not a collection of objects, so `toPopulationRoles[i]` and `toPopulationRoles.length` are improper uses

Comment: hmm ok yes. I tried it now with toPopulationRoles.options.length but it also not works. do you have a little example/solution for me? Maybe Im totally wrong ^^